# I am not able to import data in sqoop via sqoop all tables

Tags: database, hadoop, sqoop

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ **sqoop import-all-tables -m=4 --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" --username=retail_dba --password=cloudera --warehouse-dir=/user/cloudera/sqoop-import**

Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
16/05/26 10:31:30 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.5-cdh5.4.2
16/05/26 10:31:30 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
16/05/26 10:31:32 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
16/05/26 10:31:33 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
16/05/26 10:31:33 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `categories` AS t LIMIT 1
16/05/26 10:31:33 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `categories` AS t LIMIT 1
16/05/26 10:31:33 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce
Note: /tmp/sqoop-cloudera/compile/cc4bbc7353018a0c34e03cbc6701dc23/categories.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
16/05/26 10:31:43 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-cloudera/compile/cc4bbc7353018a0c34e03cbc6701dc23/categories.jar
16/05/26 10:31:43 WARN manager.MySQLManager: It looks like you are importing from mysql.
16/05/26 10:31:43 WARN manager.MySQLManager: This transfer can be faster! Use the --direct
16/05/26 10:31:43 WARN manager.MySQLManager: option to exercise a MySQL-specific fast path.
16/05/26 10:31:43 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Setting zero DATETIME behavior to convertToNull (mysql)
16/05/26 10:31:43 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of categories
16/05/26 10:31:44 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
16/05/26 10:31:47 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
16/05/26 10:31:47 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1:8032
16/05/26 10:31:56 INFO db.DBInputFormat: Using read commited transaction isolation
16/05/26 10:31:56 INFO db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat: BoundingValsQuery: SELECT MIN(`category_id`), MAX(`category_id`) FROM `categories`
16/05/26 10:31:56 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:4
16/05/26 10:31:57 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1464283628429_0001
16/05/26 10:31:59 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1464283628429_0001
16/05/26 10:31:59 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1464283628429_0001/
16/05/26 10:31:59 INFO mapreduce.Job: **Running job: job_1464283628429_0001**
```

Comment: please click on the above blue hyperlinked text to see the image i uploaded for an exact description of my issue

Comment: please see probable solution below and keep updated... if you are okay with this flag up "accepted by owner"

Comment: Please copy that text, [edit] your question, and paste it here. Don't use screenshots for code

Comment: And that warehouse directory you gave to sqoop needs to be an HDFS path, so it would have failed anyway after you started the resource manager

Comment: cricket_007: well spotted.. which I haven't highlighted in my answer,but felt like he was trying different options

Comment: @ShivaSaxena anything worked? my answer was helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did bit research on this kind of error and finally found out below 
as described in your log from screen shot, after the below log error occurred many retry errors popped up.
So doubted on resource manager.

```
Connecting to ResourceManager at quickstart.cloudera
```

I investigated and found out [this](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Apache-Hadoop-Concepts-and/To-execute-the-sqoop-command-do-we-haveto-start-any-server/td-p/26983)

> You shouldn't normally have to start any server after booting, but it looks like the YARN ResourceManager has died. It's possible there was just a little glitch when it was starting and could be fixed by running the following and trying again:

```
sudo service hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager start
```

> If you'd like to dig a little deeper or the above doesn't work, you can find the logs in /var/log/hadoop-yarn. There will be a .out file and a .log file for the ResourceManager - check both and see if there are any stack traces, error messages, etc. (or feel free to just post those files here).

Comment: Thank you very much .. Yes I found out that yarn was not running and with this command it started running. However I am still unable to import with sqoop using sqoop import-all-tables. I am giving the no. of mappers as 4 so it should one by one import all tables in 4 files. But it is getting stuck in only the first file import and is not ending. :|

Comment: I have updated my question, please look into it.. @RamPrasad

Comment: First of all for new answer new question should be raised. But looks like your job is running as it is giving tracker url http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1464283628429_0001/ as long as job runs you have to wait for the result and you can check in database whether it got imported partial result or not. and you have to see job tracker and task tracker for result from the above URL. Seems like now there is no problem.

Comment: But it is not getting over even after one hour of wait.....  :( ... and also there is not even a single byte of import ... I checked in the directory.

Comment: there might be some other cause which you need to debug Thx